# IMO 1959 - Problem 2 - Simplification of square-root values

Tags: absolute-value

I have a question on how the simplification process goes for squaring square-roots and how absolute values interact with one another. Question is from IMO Math-Olympiad 1959 #2

> $A = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{2x - 1}} + \sqrt{x - \sqrt{2x - 1}}$
>
> $A^2 = \big(\sqrt{x + \sqrt{2x - 1}}\big)^2 + 2 \big(\sqrt{x + \sqrt{2x - 1}}\big)\big(\sqrt{x - \sqrt{2x - 1}}\big) + \big(\sqrt{x - \sqrt{2x - 1}}\big)^2$
>
> ???
>
> $A^2 = 2(x + |x-1|)$

Comment: Amend the first line of your question ? 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A = \sqrt{x - \sqrt{2x - 1}}+ \color{red}{\sqrt{x +\sqrt{2x - 1}}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Wait.  You were told those two things were true?  So $A^2 = x -\sqrt{2x -1} = x + \sqrt{2x -1} + 2(\sqrt{x + \sqrt{2x -1}})(\sqrt{x - \sqrt{2x -1}}) + x - \sqrt{2x -1}$????????

Comment: My mistake, I have edited and fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a square root is always positive (or $0$). So $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\geq0$ . For example, $\sqrt{(-3)^2}=\sqrt9=3=|{-3}|$.

We also have, for *positive* $x$ and $y$ , $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt x\sqrt y$ , and $\sqrt x^2=x=|x|$.

(If they're negative, the expressions are undefined, unless you use imaginary numbers. Then there's the problem of $1=\sqrt1=\sqrt{-1\times-1}\neq\sqrt{-1}\times\sqrt{-1}=i\times i=-1$ .)

Thus (assuming that everything in a $\sqrt\;$ is non-negative, which is true if $x\geq1/2$), the middle expression in $A^2$ is

$$2\sqrt{x+\sqrt{2x-1}}\sqrt{x-\sqrt{2x-1}}$$

$$=2\sqrt{\big(x+\sqrt{2x-1}\big)\big(x-\sqrt{2x-1}\big)}$$

(use the difference of squares $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$)

$$=2\sqrt{\big(x^2-(2x-1)\big)}$$

$$=2\sqrt{\big(x^2-2x+1\big)}$$

$$=2\sqrt{(x-1)^2}$$

$$=2|x-1|$$